# Equivalence percentage between two array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, percentage, equivalence

i need a way to compare two array and compute the Equivalence percentage 
so if equivalence Percentage exceed (for example 60%) do some actions
used language is C# .NET 4.0

Comment: How are you defining "equivalence percentage"?  Is there a formula/algorithm you need to apply?

Comment: there is no algorithm

Comment: [Please don't answer bad questions.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252531/436282)

Comment: How do you define equivalence? Is it number of elements that match? Does order matter? Do you want to include relative comparisons of items (that is, if you have lists of words, do you want to compare similarities between words)? Do the lengths of the lists count? Without some idea of what you mean by "equivalence," there's no way to answer your question.

Comment: it's the intersect percentage between two array

Comment: The answer you selected is not the intersect percentage. It's the percentage of indexes such that `a[i] == j[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is poorly defined, so I've taken some broad assumptions, but here's a sample implementation that measures equivalence based on element equality:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] b = new int[] { 1, 7, 3, 4 };

int equalElements = a.Zip(b, (i, j) => i == j).Count(eq => eq);
double equivalence = (double)equalElements / Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
if (equivalence >= .6)
{
    // 60%+ equivalent
}
```

[`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): "Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences." In this case, we're comparing each element from `a` with the corresponding element from `b`, and producing `true` if they're equal. For example, we compare `1` with `1`, `2` with `7`, `3` with `3`, and `4` with `4`. We then count the number of equalities we encountered, storing this value into `equalElements`. Finally, we divide this by the total number of elements in the larger sequence, and thus get the equivalence ratio.

Comment: could you explain what have you done int a.Zip method

Comment: @user3749485 [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're comparing two int lists (or arrays, it's the same) you can compute the percentage of equivalent elements between `list1` and `list2` this way:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 3, 5, 8 };
var res = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList().Count();
float perc = (float)list1.Count() / res;
```

Comment: @user3749485 - You haven't told anyone what you want, so how can anyone write something that "works"?

Comment: +1: This was a valid alternate interpretation.

Comment: sorry bro i though i was clear :(

Comment: this doesn't consider the order of the elements / duplicate elements. doesn't work for e.g. `List<bool> list = new List<bool>() { true, false, false };`